# Karabiner - ESC held down mapped to CONTROL_L

Tags: macos, keyboard

I would like to do the following with karabiner, i am trying for the past hour, and couldn't get it to work. I want

ESCAPE key to work as ESCAPE, when it is pressed and released.
 When ESCAPE key is held down, it should work as CONTROL_L.

This is what I came up with, after many attempts, based on looking through the sample.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Change HoldingEscape to Control_L.</name>
    <identifier>private.holdingEscape_to_Control-L</identifier>
    <autogen>__HoldingKeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::VK_NONE, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, Option::NOREPEAT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the correct definition to set in your private.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
      <name>Change HoldingEscape to Control_L</name>
      <appendix>(+ When you type Escape only, send Escape)</appendix>
      <identifier>private.holdingEscape_to_Control-L</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```